# Ktor testApplication with content negotiation won't work

Tags: json, kotlin, testing, ktor, ktor-client

```kotlin
        testApplication {
            createClient {
                install(ContentNegotiation) {
                    register(ContentType.Application.Json, JacksonConverter(mapper))
                }
            }
            environment {
                config = MapApplicationConfig()
            }
            client.post("/hey") {
                headers[HttpHeaders.ContentType] = ContentType.Application.Json.toString()
                setBody(SomeBody(true))
            }
        }
```

This fails with error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to prepare request body for sending. 

        The body type is: class foodology.reified.routes.SomeBody, with Content-Type: application/json.

        If you expect serialized body, please check that you have installed the 
corresponding plugin(like `ContentNegotiation`) and set `Content-Type` header.
```

That only happens with the test client, If I mount an actual server on a random port and use the usual client, I don't get this error.

Comment: Can you please check that the `ContentNegotiation` plugin is imported from the **client** package?

Comment: It is, otherwise it wouldn't even compile. I've tried mixing them up. It doesn't compile. Client plugins cannot be used as server plugins and viceversa

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this myself yesterday - mostly reiterating the comment by [@Aleksei Tirman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13963150/aleksei-tirman):

The `ContentNegotiation-Plugin` exists in two variants, one for the the server-side of Ktor and one on the client-side for the `HttpClient` which is also used inside `testApplication{}`.

To use it during testing, make sure to import from `io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.*` and then use it like so:

```kotlin
testApplication {
    val client = createClient {
        install(HttpCookies) // this is for logging in
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
        // I'm using kotlinx.serialization, so you'd need to import that as well.
            json(Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
            })
        }
    }
    client.get("/your-url")

}
```

Comment: Damn, you're right, I didn't install it in the server side. I won't select this answer, as it's suggesting I install that in the client side, but as it can be seen in the question, I already have

Comment: alright - my answer is talking about where you import the plugin from rather than which one you have installed, which can not be seen in the question.
however your problem was different, i see that - might want to post the correct answer yourself then.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above using the ContentNegotiation-Plugin import from

```
io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
```

for `testApplication{}`worked for me as well. The error I was consistently getting before was

> Please check that you have installed the corresponding plugin(like `ContentNegotiation`) and set `Content-Type` header